# Session start only show background until I manually startX through tty1

Tags: apt, gnome, xorg, session

Some info about my setup before I start my novel:
Ubuntu 16.04 gnome gdm3 (was using `lightdm` when I first had the problem, but switched trying to see if it fixes the problem).

When I am logging into my session, I can select my session and type my password just fine, but then only the background loads and nothing else. If I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and manually launch the serverX through startX, my session loads fine.
On a related problem, I also can't lock my session (through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, or <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, or the GUI)

Now, this problem does not occured at a random time. I recently messed everything related to package management big time. And I can't remember precisely every thing that I did.

Here is some large view of what I did if this might help.

- I tried to install python 3.6, but it wouldn't let me go over python 3.5. So trying to be smart, I edited `/etc/apt/sources.list` and added some debug repo I think. (I since reverted back the changes to `sources.list`).

  ```
  #deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2)]/ xenial main restricted

  # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
  # newer versions of the distribution.
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
  # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

  ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
  ## distribution.
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
  # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
  ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
  ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
  # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
  # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
  ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
  ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
  ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
  ## security team.
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
  # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
  # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

  ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
  ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
  ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
  ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
  ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
  # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

  ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
  ## 'partner' repository.
  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
  ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
  # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
  # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
  # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
  # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
  # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
  ```
- Then trying to force python 3.6 to be installed (I failed), I messed up everything. From my point of view, `git` suddenly was no longer installed on my machine, and everytime I wanted to run `apt-get` I had some unresolved dependencies (moslty `git`, `python3`, `libperl`).
- I then tried to solve this `apt` issue. At some point managed to accidentally uninstall `apt-get` (and `aptitude` was not installed either) amongst other packages...
- At this point, the machine behaves *normally* I can lock my session, I can use `vim`, `gcc` and `gdb` just fine (all is fine for me but `git`).
- Then I lock my session and go into the weekend. And this morning I come back to a black screen, literally nothing is displayed on the screen.
- I hard reboot my machine and nothing starts (at this point I cannot even try to log in my session). So I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, and try to manually start startX (which fails miserably).
- I then proceed to fix (I guess) my package issue through:

  ```
  sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf
  ```

  And reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` and finally manage to start the serverX and my session normally

  ```
  sudo apt --fix-broken install 
  sudo dpkg --configure -a 
  sudo apt-get update 
  sudo apt-get upgrade 
  sudo dpkg --configure -a 
  sudo apt-get -f install 
  sudo apt-get full-upgrade  
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop  
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall update-manager  
  startx
  ```

  Everything was fine, I was happy (I noticed that the environment wasn't exactly the same as before (not the same font in the terminal) but whatever, I could work fine. (even `git` was back)
- Then I tried to lock my session --> impossible
- When I rebooted trying to fix the lock issue, I noticed that once I typed my password to log into my session it loaded the background and nothing else (Once again startX through `tty1` solves the issue to log to my session).

  To solve the issue, I tried a few things:

  ```
  sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
  ```

  I tried with gdm3 and lightdm: same issue both times

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-session
  sudo apt-get install x11-common
  sudo apt-get install xserver-common
  sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
  sudo apt-get install gnome
  sudo apt-get install unity
  ```

I'd be happy to provide any log file or anything of course, if you are crazy enough to want to help me through my mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the desktop environment to kubuntu-desktop and sddm solved my issue. Session boot fine and I can lock my screen !!!!!!!!

I guess that the issue was coming from ubuntu-desktop (The config files must have been messed up somewhere) since I had the issue with both lightdm and gdm when using ubuntu-desktop.